# Pandora for podcasts

Tags: android, recommendation-engine, podcast

What is an Android app that

- Lets a user create a station that automatically plays recommended podcasts based on the user's rating of each individual episode?
- Adheres to Google's Material design guidelines (Stitcher does not do this)?
- Lets the user view which podcasts that they liked?